# Множественное наследование C++ помогите))

Tags: c++

Описать два базовых класса с защищен переменной типа char (в Первом - фамилия, в другом - им "я). В Первому из них описать функцию записи фамилии в обратном порядке, а в другом - превращение всех букв имени в Большие. Предусмотреть вывод преобразованной информации на экран. використовуючи множества подражания, описать производной класс с функцией задания этих переменных. В главной функции main ввести эти значения с с помощью обращения к функции с производного класса и вивести Преобразование информацию на экран, використовуючи Функции из базовых классов.

Почему она выводит не все символи?

Код

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "algorithm"
#include "string"
#include "Windows.h"
using namespace std;

class Mystring
{
protected: char str1, str3;
public: 
    void  mystring()
    {
        char str1[20];
        char str3[20];

        cout << " прізвище : ";
        cin.getline(str1,20);
        strcpy(str3, strrev(str1));
        cout << str3;   
    }
};

class bas2
{
protected:char str,str2;
public:
    void obr()
    {
        char str[20];
        char str2[20];

        cout << "Введіть ім’я: ";
        cin.getline(str,20);
        strcpy(str2, strupr(str));
        cout <<"ім’я:"<< str2;
    }
};

class pohid :  public bas2,public Mystring
{
public:
    void vvid(char STRING)
    { 
        bas2::str2 = STRING;
        Mystring::str3 = STRING;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    pohid cc;
    char str3;
    char str2;
    cout<<"Ввести прізвище"<<endl;
    cin>>str3;

    cin>>str2;
    cc.mystring();
    cc.obr();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В чем заключается ваш вопрос по множественному наследованию?

Comment: програма не виводит все символи...например функция записи фамилии в зворотном порядке (strrev) виводит только после  3 символа...например написал "ИВАНОВ" а оно виводит ВОНА а остальние два символа "ВИ" где?

Comment: Вы вводите один символ, вместо строки:      <code>void vvid(char STRING)</code> И почему поля в один символ, когда вам нужно хранить фамилию и имя: <code>protected: char str1, str3;</code> Тут массив char  нужен.

Comment: Один `char` хранит только одну букву. У вас названия полей класса и переменных (которые сделаны в виде массива) в функциях совпадают.

Comment: Главная причина в том, что без теоретических знаний вы хотите писать код

Answer (score 1):

Требование задачи не соответствует тому, что вы пытались делать, но не получилось. Требуется примерно такое:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Mystring {
protected:
    char surname[20];
public:
    void  inverse() { strrev(surname); }
    void print_surname() const { cout << surname << endl; }
};
class Name {
protected:
    char firstName[20], up[20];
public:
    void print_firstName(bool capitals = false) {
        if(capitals) {
            cout << up << endl;
         }
        else
             cout << firstName <<endl;
    }
};
class Pohid : public Mystring, public Name {
public:
    Pohid() {
        cout << "enter surname \n" ;
        cin.getline(surname, 20);
        cout << "enter firstname \n";
        cin.getline(firstName, 20);
        int n = strlen(firstName);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            up[i] = toupper(firstName[i]);
    }
};

int main()
{    
    Pohid p;
    p.print_firstName();
    p.print_surname();
    // теперь напечатаем фамилию в обратном порядке, а имя с большими буквами
    p.inverse();
    p.print_firstName(true);
    p.print_surname();
    return 0;
}
```

Если вы поймете как и почему, то надеюсь это будет в пользу того, чтоб  дальше вы писали осмысленные вещи

Comment: етот  код не доработан...много ошибок))

Comment: @Олег Флуд, когда не знаешь,  лучше помолчать, чем говорить глупости

Comment: да да..........

Answer (score -2):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include<string>
 using namespace std;
 class Mystring {
    protected:
   char surname[20];
public:
void  inverse() { strrev(surname); }
void print_surname() const { cout << surname << endl; }
};
 class Name {
protected:
char firstName[20];
public:
void  verse() { strupr(firstName); }
void print_firstName() const { cout << firstName << endl; }
};
class Pohid : public Mystring, public Name {
public:
Pohid() {
    cout << "enter surname \n";
    cin.getline(surname, 20);
    cout << "enter firstname \n";
    cin.getline(firstName, 20);

 }
};

int main()
{
Pohid p;
p.print_firstName();
p.print_surname();
// теперь напечатаем фамилию в обратном порядке, а имя с большими буквами
p.inverse();
p.verse();
p.print_firstName();
p.print_surname();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: вот код....доработал:)

Comment: всего лишь сделал так, что   firstName   не возвращается в начальное состояние никакой функцией.  Т.е. по вашему мнению испортить данные и убрать инвариант, назывется доработал? ..  И потом тут не требуется дорабатывать коды ответчиков. В таком случаи я возьму и напишу  ту же логику с помощью STL  контейнеров и альгоритмов, кто то использует альгоритмы еще круче..  А автору вопроса нужно всего лишь понять как  решить свою проблему, а не чтоб его запутали разными верными и неверными вариантами